# Option not being selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select a specific option of these two select:

```
<select class="crs-country form-control required" name="country" id="customer-state" data-region-id="customer-region"></select>

<select id="customer-region" name="region" class="form-control required"></select>
```

using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#customer-state option[value="Italy"]').prop("selected", true);
  $('#customer-region option[value="Liguria"]').prop("selected", true);
})
```

but no chance to get this working. I also created a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5ok6ruxd/1/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#customer-state option[value="Italy"]').prop("selected", true);
  $('#customer-region option[value="Liguria"]').prop("selected", true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://country-regions.github.io/country-region-selector/crs.min.js"></script>

<select class="crs-country form-control required" name="country" id="customer-state" data-region-id="customer-region"></select>

<select id="customer-region" name="region" class="form-control required"></select>
```

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't work as you haven't added jQuery as a library. Add it, and it works.

Comment: @putvande I fix that, but I still have the same problem, just on the region select..

Comment: Open your console, it says : `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: check the updated jsfiddle

Comment: My bet is that document ready runs before the data is loaded and you do not trigger an event to say you selected a value to fill in the next set which also will rely on a delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is probably because the `crs.min.js` plugin you've loaded relies on listening to the `onchange` event on the `<select>` element in order to update the region dropdown. Therefore, if you trigger/dispatch the `onchange` event manually on the parent `<select>` element, then it should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#customer-state option[value="Italy"]').prop("selected", true).parent().trigger('change');
  $('#customer-region option[value="Liguria"]').prop("selected", true);
})
```

```html
<script src="http://country-regions.github.io/country-region-selector/crs.min.js" id="crs"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="crs-country form-control required" name="country" id="customer-state" data-region-id="customer-region"></select>

<select id="customer-region" name="region" class="form-control required"></select>
```

**Even better:** You actually don't need to select the `<option>` element using jQuery: you can simply set the `<select>` element's value to the desired selected option, and the correct `<option>` will automatically be selected. I prefer this method because it makes your code a lot more readable, and slightly more performant as the browser does not have to traverse through all the nested `<option>` elements to match the attribute selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#customer-state').val('Italy').trigger('change');
  $('#customer-region').val('Liguria');
})
```

```html
<script src="http://country-regions.github.io/country-region-selector/crs.min.js" id="crs"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="crs-country form-control required" name="country" id="customer-state" data-region-id="customer-region"></select>

<select id="customer-region" name="region" class="form-control required"></select>
```

Comment: @atelion Thanks, glad that I helped!